# Formatting a date from d"-"mmm"-"yy to "YYYY-MM-DD" outputs invalid year

Tags: google-apps-script, date-formatting

I have a column formatted as `"-"mmm"-"yy`, e.g. `13-May-18`. I determined this by going to Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format within the Google Sheet.

I've tried using the following to convert to YYYY-MM-DD.

```
  ss.getRange(B2:B).setNumberFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

But it returns `0218-05-13` instead of the expected `2018-05-13`.

I also tried the following, but it returns that same erroneous date `0218-05-13`.

```
 var vals = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); 
      
      for(var j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) 
    {
      var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vals[j][0]), "GMT", "YYYY-MM-DD");
      ss.getRange(j+2,2,1,1).setValue([[newDate]])
      
    }
```

In the same sheet, I have another date column formatted as `D-MMM-YY`, and it behaves as expected when I run the codes above to produce `2018-05-13`.

What is the deal with the format `d"-"mmm"-"yy`? Is yy being interpreted as a string? How does GAS come up with `02` to tack on the front?

Is my best option to fix this to just loop through each value in the column, grab the last two digits, add 2000 and use that value to replace the last two digits and reformat from there?

**Edit**

The output of `vals[j][0]` is `Mon May 28 00:00:00 GMT-04:56 0218`.

This problem is not consistently reproducible. Theoretically, the following should reproduce my problem, but it doesn't.

```
// create sheet
  var newSheetID = SpreadsheetApp.create("example").getId();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetID).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  // set B1 to include problem date 
  ss.getRange("B1").setValue("28-May-18")
  
    // format the range to the problematic format
  ss.getRange("B1").setNumberFormat("d'-'mmm'-'yy")
  
  // this reformats as expected 2018-05-28
  ss.getRange("B1").setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

The problem doesn't occur in the adjacent date column, nor does it occur in every cell within the column where the problem does occur.

I did find a fix for the problem. I just have to convert the values to a string first, and then to a date.

```
ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow(),1).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow(),1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I can post this as the answer, but would likely be more helpful to know why this isn't reproducible in a new sheet like @TheMaster mentioned. I'd rather not post my sheet, but am willing look into any ideas anyone has.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, `Y` and `D` are Week year and Day in year, respectively. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html For example, when you modified `YYYY-MM-DD` to `yyyy-MM-dd`, will your issue be changed?

Comment: @Tanaike, Thanks for catching that, but `yyyy-MM-dd` returns the exact same erroneous date.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that in order to correctly replicate your situation, I would like to confirm your sample Spreadsheet for replicating it, and think of the issue. How about this? Unfortunately, in my environment, I cannot replicate your issue. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: Is the error consistently reproducible? Say, in a new spreadsheet, new column A with the newly set format?

Comment: @Marion - also, are you sure the correct date is passed to `Date` constructor? Show us what the `vals[j][0]` looks like. No repro as well.

Comment: @Marion - there you go. Can't you just set the column format to plaintext? Also, you can simply `setNumberFormat('@')` prior to retrieving the date to make sure it is plaintext programmatically.

Comment: Are the dates in your spreadsheet really dates? Check type using `=type(b:b)` and drag fill. They should all be 1. And `=isdate(b:b)` and drag fill. They should be true

Comment: @TheMaster - I think they are dates (judging by what `getValues()` returns), but the format is set to a custom date-time format. The idea that this is likely the case is reinforced by the fact that the OP says setting format to plaintext solves the issue. But, that's just my assumption, would be best to hear from Marion

Comment: @OlegValter Personally Never a fan of date <=> string conversion.  I believe in maintaining types across platforms unless absolutely necessary. *think they are dates (judging by what getValues() returns)* This  suggests otherwise: *nor does it occur in every cell within the column where the problem does occur.* I think some of them are not dates. May be extra space or even a typo.

Comment: @TheMaster - yeah, some of them might not be ( I also find it odd ), but afaik the "dd-month-yy" format can not be achieved without explicitly choosing it as a custom format. Don't argue there are no issues with the data itself, though, may be the case. Re: data type preservation - well, I never argued against it? Just mentioned plaintext in regards to the workaround the OP found

Comment: @OlegValter Neither am I arguing. Just making my opinions/beliefs in the open. I don't  support such workarounds as they will mask real errors/issues.

Comment: @TheMaster and @OlegValter Thanks for your feedback. Interestingly, `=type(b:b)` returns `2`, which is text, while `isdate(b:b)` returns `TRUE` for all values in the column. Would be great to avoid converting to string/text.

Comment: @Marion Type does this for all values or only some? Select B:B > format > date and then custom format.

Comment: @TheMaster Correction: `=type(b:b)` returns `1`. I had checked the processed sheet instead of the original. Looking at the original, `=type(b:b)` returns `1`. `isdate(b:b)` returns `TRUE` both before and after I Select B:B > format > date.

Comment: @TheMaster To confirm, the year still gets mis-formatted when I Select B:B > format > date. Type returns 1 for all values.

Comment: @Marion Well, there you have it. Year is mistyped. Manually correct it before doing anything else.

Comment: @TheMaster - ah, I see, I tend to think that I said something on the contrary when someone starts with "personally, ". That said, I understand your sentiment - it is better to have the data well-formed or spend some effort to ensure that beforehand. Marion, agreed with TheMaster here, there is no other apparent reason other than the year typo